# Using CreateDecryotor() in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, encryption

I was wondering if anyone could help me out with an error I am getting in PowerShell.  I am having no issue with creating the encryptor shown below:

```
 $Crypto = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider 
 $IV = New-Object System.Byte[] 16 
 $Crypto.GetNonZeroBytes($iv) 

 $RIJSym = new-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged   

 [byte[]] $Key = ('mysecret$%@').ToCharArray() 
 $Encryptor = $RIJSym.CreateEncryptor($Key,$IV)
```

But for what ever reason I am having an issue when I want to decrypt my key, here is what I am using and the error I get when the Program runs:

`$Decrypted = $RIJSym.CreateDecryptor($Encryptor)`

Error Message

```
 Cannot find an overload for "CreateDecryptor" and the argument count: "1".  
 At line:15 char:1
 + $DeCryp = $rijSym.CreateDecryptor($encryptor)
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Comment: What object is $RIJSym. How is it created? What are you doing with it before the call that fails?

Comment: CreateDecryptor doesn't take a single argument. You either need to define the key and IV on the object beforehand, or specify them to the method. Also, your code and your error don't match up. One says `$Encryptor` (Error), and the other says `$Encrypted` (Code).

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Sorry that was my bad I was working from two different files trying out the same program to see what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says it all... `CreateDecryptor()` doesn't have an overload the uses onl a single argument. The valid overloads are:

```
PS > $RIJSym.CreateDecryptor

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform CreateDecryptor(byte[] rgbKey, byte[] rgbIV)
System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform CreateDecryptor()
```

You need to create the decryptor the same way you created the encrypter: by specifying the key and IV. Ex.

```
$Decrypted = $RIJSym.CreateDecryptor($Key, $IV)
```